# Why does pythonanywhere show up DisallowedHost

Tags: pythonanywhere

Why does pythonanywhere show up DisallowedHost at :

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'kimmy.pythonanywhere.com'. You may need to
>   add 'kimmy.pythonanywhere.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

I have set up `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['kimmy.pythonanywhere.com']` in the `setting.py` but nothing change.

Comment: hi, please make this understandable. both reformulate and reformat the question

Comment: did you reload your webapp on the web tab after changing *settings.py*?